# Getting the size of an aggregate as if it was packed

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing some network code and was wondering if it's possible to get the size of an arbitrary aggregate as if it was tightly packed.

In my case the size of the type

```
struct Header
{
    std::int8_t priority = 0;
    std::uint16_t sender = 0;
    std::uint16_t receiver = 0;
    std::uint64_t userSize = 0;
};
```

is 16 bytes, because of the default alignment.

I've tried to use polymorphism but this doesn't change the alignment of the base type, unfortunately:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
template <typename T>
struct packed_size_helper : T { };
#pragma pack(pop)

template <typename T>
constexpr std::size_t packed_size = sizeof(packed_size_helper<T>);
```

Basically I'm trying to get the buffer size that is necessary to hold all members of `Header`. I know I could just pack `Header` itself and use `sizeof(Header)` or hard code the buffer size, so this question is mostly out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

What you could try is using placement `new` on a block of pre-initialize memory. Not sure if this is guaranteed to work, but something like:

```
char* mem = new char[sizeof(Header)];
std::memset(mem, 0xff, sizeof(Header));
Header* sizer = new (reinterpret_cast<void *>(mem)) Header;
size_t packed_size = 0;
for (char* ptr = mem; ptr < mem + sizeof(Header); ++ptr) {
    if (*ptr == 0x00) ++packed_size;
}
delete[] mem;
sizer = nullptr;
```

Obviously, if the default `ctor` is allowed to over-write padding this won't work.

Comment: Interesting approach. There are only two things that bother me. 1) Since it uses `new` it can't run at compile time (c++17). 2) If any of the members doesn't default to `0` the result is incorrect.